# SQL, Then, Replace

Tags: sql, vertica

Getting an error in on THEN in my query.

```
case WHEN (I.stackoverflow in 'VBA', 'SQL') 
        THEN replace(I.superuser, '~', '.') 
     WHEN (I.stackoverflow in 'Java', 'design') 
        THEN substr(position_name, (instr(position_name, '_')+2), (len(position_name)-instr(position_name, '_'))) 
     WHEN (I.stackoverflow in 'finance') 
       THEN ((position_name||'.')||currency) 
     WHEN (I.stackoverflow in 'philosophy', 'gaming') 
        THEN ((blah||'.')||currency) 
     WHEN (I.stackoverflow in 'personal finance') 
        THEN cast('text', money) 
     ELSE replace(I.superuser, '~', '.') 
END AS stackexchange
```

If I comment out the `THEN` I get an error on WHEN (which appears after my then)

error is:

```
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: 4856
```

So far I have changed my bracketing approach. Was getting an error on `VBA` now `I.superuser` is red in my query.

updated:

```
case WHEN I.stackoverflow in ('VBA', 'SQL') 
        THEN replace(I.superuser, '~', '.') 
     WHEN I.stackoverflow in ('Java', 'design') 
        THEN substr(position_name, (instr(position_name, '_')+2), (len(position_name)-instr(position_name, '_'))) 
     WHEN I.stackoverflow in ('finance') 
       THEN ((position_name||'.')||currency) 
     WHEN I.stackoverflow in ('philosophy', 'gaming') 
        THEN ((blah||'.')||currency) 
     WHEN I.stackoverflow in ('personal finance') 
        THEN cast('text', money) 
     ELSE replace(I.superuser, '~', '.') 
END AS stackexchange
```

Comment: `CASE` needs a closing `END` clause.

Comment: Put the whole query at first to not guess what's wrong, you also have From TableName as I and so on

Comment: hi guys, i do have an end as in my query, i have edited question

Comment: @excelguy Why don't post the complete query, Instead of leaving users to different interpretations?  Also, could you please post the error you're getting.  It almost feels like you're missing syntax somewhere.

Comment: i've posted the case statement, the full query can get quite long.

Comment: What is the **exact** error message you get? I'm pretty sure there is some message together with the error codes.

Comment: I am querying Vertica

Comment: I believe you got the parenthesis wrong. 
case WHEN I.stackoverflow in ( 'VBA', 'SQL')

Comment: @Blurryface okay we are getting somewhere, now i get an error at the first `I.superuser`

Comment: Did you change the parenthesis for all the relevant 'When's? Again what's the error that you see?

Comment: @Blurryface , same error. Syntax error near ',' but i do see that `I.superuser` is red in my query.

Comment: @excelguy Why don't you update the code to its most recent version? So everyone would be on same page. Nobody's going to read through all the comments to see where we are!

Comment: @Blurryface , sent you a message in chat

Answer (score 1):

Your CASE statement is missing an ELSE and an END:

```
select 
    case when I.Stack in ('VBA','SQL','Excel') 
    THEN replace (I.Overflow, '~', '.')
    ELSE <what do you want to do when your case isn't true?>
    END
    AS <it helps to have a column alias for logic like this>
FROM
    sometable AS I
```

Answer (score 0):

If you indent your code properly, it's easy to see why your code is not working.

```
select 
    case 
        when I.Stack in ('VBA','SQL','Excel') THEN replace (I.Overflow, '~', '.')
    end -- missing
```